# Download old IMAP emails using POP3 in Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, pop3

I have a web/email hosting account with emails configured in outlook. I recently realised that I had accidentally configured Outlook 2013 to use IMAP instead of POP3 when I received a notification that I was running out of hosting space and saw that emails were taking over 2GB of the space.

I deleted the IMAP account from outlook and re entered it (same email address account) this time using POP3 but it is only downloading new emails. All my old emails and folders etc are still on the server (I can see them using the webmail within cPanel)

What is the best way for me to retrieve my old emails from the server (and folder structure) to have them in a POP3 Outlook connection from now on?

thanks.

Comment: Your webmail view is just an IMAP view of the account.  I would set it back to IMAP in your client, then move the emails to a folder that exists locally in the client.

Comment: Hi @sunk818 I have lodged a ticket with their Tech Support team as suggested, I just figured this would be more of a generic thing not something specific to my host. Tyson I did try this, but in outlook the dragged folders under the POP3 account were all empty (nothing downloaded)

Comment: Tyson's suggestion is best as it doesn't involve tech support. Just move the IMAP e-mail it to a local folder, then use POP3 going forward.